# app se cierra al definir "theme" al manifest

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

estoy intentando crear un slplash screen. Ya la tengo pero se me sigue mostrando el action bar y yo quiero que se muestre a pantalla completa. He añdido esta linea al manifest: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"` para que se muestre a pantalla completa, pero la aplicacion se estrella nada mas empezar al añadir esta linea. Este es el manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.luilli.splashscreen3">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashScreen3">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
            android:exported="true"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

no me aparece ningun error en build ni en run. Tan solo en logcat aparece este:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.luilli.splashscreen3/com.luilli.splashscreen3.SplashActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el mensaje de error que aparece cuando la App se *estrella*, como dices. Bueno, una App no es un vehículo, pero se entiende :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado añadiendo este theme en lugar del que indiqué inicialmente: `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te fue más útil.

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error indica el problema:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.luilli.splashscreen3/com.luilli.splashscreen3.SplashActivity}:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
> theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Indica que necesitas usar un tema "Theme.AppCompat" (o descendiente) con esta actividad.

Puedes revisar en tu archivo `styles.xml` que temas "Theme.AppCompat" o descendientes tienes :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y definelo en tu Activity dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```